# $\infty$-category of functors commuting with all sifted colimits.

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory

Let $\mathbf{C}$ be a small  $\infty$-category.  Let $\text{Psh}\;\mathbf{C}$ be the presentable  category of   all $\infty$-functors  from $\mathbf{C}^{\text{op}}$ to the category of  spaces

Let $\mathcal{X}$ be a co-closed $\infty$-category. Denote
by $\mathcal{H}(\text{Psh}\;\mathbf{C};\mathcal{X})$ the $\infty$-groupoid of all those functors
$\text{Psh}\;\mathbf{C}\to \mathcal{X}$ commuting with all sifted colimits in $\text{Psh}\;\mathbf{C}$.

On the other hand, let $P\mathbf{C}$ be the category of formal  finite
disjoint unions in
$\mathbf{C}$.  We have a fully faithful embedding $\iota:P\mathbf{C}\to \text{Psh}\;\mathbf{C}$

I have read somewhere (if I remember correctly) that in some examples  the restriction by $\iota$:
$$
\mathcal{H}(\text{Psh}\;\mathbf{C},\mathcal{X})\to \text{Funct}(P\mathbf{C},\mathcal{X})
$$
is an equivalence, where $\text{Funct}$ is the $\infty$-groupoid of all $\infty$-functors.  Is it true ( maybe  under some conditions)?  Thanks!

Comment: Your definitions are strange. What you call Ind seems to be what everyone else calls Psh.

Comment: Agree, thanks! D

Comment: I think you may be able to derive this from Lurie's HTT Proposition 5.3.6.2, using the fact that adding all sifted colimits and coproducts means adding all colimits.